# Cakephp:: Get data from others table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have this model called User, this model use "Users" table. This model is specially designed for admin to login. This model has "id, username, password, created, modified" fields.

Now, If I want to add more users, "normal users", users that can't login. What should I do?

Currently, I created new model called "Person", use "people" table, which has "id, username, email" fields.

From my admin panel(User model), how do I view the normal users(person model) data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you are talking about authentication and authorization, you can check out the built-in [acl](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists) and [auth](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication) in cakephp.

second, to use Person model

```
$personModel = ClassRegistry::init('Person');
$person = $personModel->findById($id);
```

Comment: where do I put this line: $personModel = ClassRegistry::init('Person');?? In user model?

Comment: yes, or somewhere else, whenever you need to use another model, use this line to 'import' that model and do anything you want

Comment: After I put the code you gave, it gives me this error: Error: Database table people for model Person was not found. But my database already has that table

Comment: I put "var $personModel = ClassRegistry::init('Person');" in user model, it gives me this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /.../app/models/user.php on line 10.

Comment: Parse error means maybe you should put this line in a function, not class.

Comment: Person model will check person table, if you are using another one, add "var $useTable = 'other table';" in Person class.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to handle this is to store all people in the users table and then add a group_id foreign key to link to the Groups table. Your groups table then has 1, Admin and 2, Normal User as the groups.

So your users table would look like this

```
users
-----
id, username, password, group_id, created, modified
```

and groups

```
groups
------
id, name
```

Link up your Users model to your Groups model with a belongsTo relationship

```
var $belongsTo = array('Group');
```

Now in your admin page you can see each type of user and tell if they are admin users or normal users with a simple fetch, or you can filter by group which group you want to look at.

This also plays really nicely if you are utilizing ACL component to handle access to your app. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists